# Implementar la subida de imagenes por API en php para despues subirla con POST desde una app en android studio

Tags: php, mysql, android-studio, json, api

Tengo un API en php que guarda datos en una base de datos en mi servidor, guarda datos que son texto y numéricos pero no me percaté que tengo un campo de una imagen, así que estoy intentando subir una imagen por esta API pero en si no sé como implementarle la subida de archivos o imagenes para que me suba tanto como los campos que son texto o números como la imagen, todos juntos, aqui esta el API:

post.php

```
<?php
   require_once('exceptions/recordnotfoundexception.php');
   require_once('connections/mysqlconnection.php');
   require_once('person.php');

class Post {

      private $idPost;    
      private $description;
      private $postphoto;
      private $postdate;
      private $person;

      public function getIdPost() { return $this->idPost; }
      public function setIdPost($idPost) { $this->idPost = $idPost; }
      public function getDescription() { return $this->description; }
      public function setDescription($description) { $this->description = $description; }
      public function getPostDate() { return $this->postdate; }
      public function setPostDate($postdate) { $this->postdate = $postdate; }
      public function getPostPhoto() { return $this->postphoto; }
      public function setPostPhoto($postphoto) { $this->postphoto = $postphoto; }    
      public function getPerson() { return $this->person; }
      public function setPerson($person) { $this->person = $person; }    

      public function __construct() {
         if(func_num_args() == 0) {
            $this->idPost = 0;
            $this->description = '';
            $this->postdate = '';
            $this->postphoto = '';           
            $this->person = new Person();
      }

      if(func_num_args() == 5) {
            $this->idPost = func_get_arg(0);
            $this->description = func_get_arg(1);
            $this->postphoto = func_get_arg(2);
            $this->postdate = func_get_arg(3);
            $this->person = func_get_arg(4);
       }

       public function add() {         
           $connection = MySqlConnection::getConnection();
           $statement = 'insert into post(description, postDate, postPhoto, idPerson) values (?, ?, ?, ?)';
           $command = $connection->prepare($statement);
           $command->bind_param('sssi', $this->description, $this->postdate, $this->postphoto, $this->person);
           $result = $command->execute();
           mysqli_stmt_close($command);
          $connection->close();
          return $result;
      }
```

Y este es su controlador:

postcontroller.php

```
<?php
   require_once("models/post.php");

   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
   {        
         if(isset($_POST['description']) && 
         isset($_POST['postdate']) &&
         isset($_POST['postphoto']) &&
         isset($_POST['person']))
         {        
              $parametersOk = true;
              $valuesOk = true;
              if ($valuesOk) 
              { 
                 try 
                {
                   $person = new Person();
                }
                catch (RecordNotFoundException $ex) 
                {
                   $valuesOk = false;
                   echo json_encode(array(
                      'status' => 3,
                      'message' => $ex->getMessage()
                   ));
               }                
          }
          if ($valuesOk) 
          {
              $post = new Post();
              $post->setDescription($_POST['description']);
              $post->setPostDate($_POST['postdate']);
              $post->setPostPhoto($_POST['postphoto']);             
              $post->setPerson($_POST['person']);
              if ($post->add())
                  echo json_encode(array(
                      'status' => 0,
                      'message' => 'Post added successfully'
                  ));
              else
                  echo json_encode(array(
                      'status' => 4,
                      'message' => 'Could not add post'
                ));                                                                             
           }       
       }             
       else
       {
          echo json_encode(array(
              'status' => 1,
              'message' => 'missing parameters'
          ));
       }
  }
```

En si, los datos se suben por el archivo postcontroller.php pero tengo esta API que sube la imagen y es esta:

uploadImage.php

```
 <?php  
   require_once("models/connections/mysqlconnection.php");  
   $upload_path = 'images/';    
   $server_ip = gethostbyname(gethostname());
   $upload_url = 'http://'.$server_ip.'/DeviceCamera/'.$upload_path;    
   $response = array();

   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
        if(isset($_POST['name']) and isset($_FILES['image']['name'])) {         
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $fileinfo = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name']);         
            $extension = $fileinfo['extension'];                
            $file_url = $upload_url.getFileName().'.'.$extension;                   
            $file_path = $upload_path.getFileName().'.'.$extension;                     
            try {               
                $connection = MySqlConnection::getConnection();
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$file_path);
                $statement = "insert into photo (name, image) values ('$name', '$file_url')";
                if(mysqli_query($connection, $statement)) {
                    echo json_encode(array(
                        'status' => 0,
                        'message' => 'Image added successfully',
                        'url' => $file_url
                   ));                  
                }               
               else
                   echo json_encode(array(
                    'status' => 4,
                    'message' => 'Could not add Image'
                ));
           }catch(RecordNotFoundException $ex){
               echo json_encode(array(
                    'status' => 3,
                    'message' => $ex->getMessage()
                ));
            }                   
            mysqli_close($connection);
         } else {
            $response['error']=true;
            $response['message']='Please choose a file';
       }
   }

function getFileName(){
    $connection = MySqlConnection::getConnection();
    $query = "select max(idImage) as id from photo";
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($connection, $query));
    mysqli_close($connection);
    if($result['id']==null)
        return 1; 
    else 
        return ++$result['id']; 
}
```

En android studio mando a llamar el archivo uploadImage.php para subir la imagen al servidor pero solo funciona con la imagen, mi pregunta es, ¿como puedo implementar lo de uploadImage.php en post.php y postcontroller.php para que me suba la imagen y los demas campos al servidor?
Gracias por su atención y espero su respuesta